# Angular ng-repeat pass parameter to href link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, grails

I have an existing grails app, built using GSPs and custom tagLibs. I need to incorporate some new code that uses AngularJS.
I am new to AngularJS.

Specifically, I have existing links that were generated with custom tags, such as:

```
<g:custonSearchLink id="${ent.id}" >
```

that evaluate to

```
<a href="fullPath/controllerName/method/X", onclick="jQuery.ajax((type:'POST', url:'fullPath/controllerName/method/X', success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('tableDiv').html(data);}, error:function(...)){}});return false" >...
```

where X is the id param. I need to have the ng-repeat generate these links, and pass the "X" param value into the href and ajax url paths.

So I understand that I can just use the nested curly braces " {{}}" to pass the X param from the object into the href string,

```
<li ng-repeat="obj in myList track by obj.id" >
  <a href="fullPath/controllerName/method/{{obj.id}}"
```

but the onclick ajax url is nested in a single quoted string inside the onclick string. How can I pass the "X" param into that? 
This does not work:

```
onclick="jQuery.ajax((type:'POST', url:'fullPath/controllerName/method/{{obj.id}}',
```

Note that the "fullPath" in my case is "https://localhost:8453/" since the server that is responding to the AJAX call is running on a different port than the server hosting the GSP.

Comment: you can't pass angular scope variables into `onclick`. Angular scope variables aren't in global namespace that onclick references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use ng-click

and define a javascript function in your angular controller in the same scope and invoke ajax using $http provider.

```
<a ng-click="invoke(obj.id)" />

$scope.invoke = function(id){
   $http({
          method:'POST', 
          url:fullPath/controllerName/method/id
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I added params to the $http call, and a successCallback to call jQuery to update my target div with the response, and everything works.

Answer (score 3):

Using [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) and [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) allows you to use AngularJS scope variables in javascript event handlers. Like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="someItem in list track by someItem.id">
  <a ng-href="/your/url/to/this/id/{{ someItem.id }}"></a>
  <button ng-click="$scope.someAction(someItem.id)"></button>
</div>
```

So your specific click event handler would be:

```
ng-click="jQuery.ajax((type:'POST', url:'fullPath/controllerName/method/{{obj.id}}'"
```

As mentioned by Shashi, you can fire the HTTP request in a scope function, though the way you are currently handling this with inline AJAX should work.

Comment: This works, thank you! I put the $http request in a scope function as Shashi suggested, and the success callback jQuery() function too. I wish I could mark both your and Shashi's answers as correct.